# Extract values from dicts inside lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to extract the values from this `JSON` file, but I having some trouble to extract the data inside from lists in the dict values. For example, in the `city` and `state`, I would like to get only the `name` values and create a `Pandas Dataframe` and select only some keys like this.

[image]

I tried using some `for` with `get` methods techniques, but without success.

```
{'birthday': ['1987-07-13T00:00:00.000Z'],
 'cpf': ['9999999999999'],
 'rg': [],
 'gender': ['Feminino'],
 'email': ['my_user@bol.com.br'],
 'phone_numbers': ['51999999999'],
 'photo': [],
 'id': 11111111,
 'duplicate_id': -1,
 'name': 'My User',
 'cnpj': [],
 'company_name': '[]',
 'city': [{'id': 0001, 'name': 'Porto Alegre'}],
 'state': [{'id': 100, 'name': 'Rio Grande do Sul', 'fs': 'RS'}],
 'type': 'Private Person',
 'tags': [],
 'pending_tickets_count': 0}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mre]. Please do not post images of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
In [123]: data
Out[123]:
{'birthday': ['1987-07-13T00:00:00.000Z'],
 'cpf': ['9999999999999'],
 'rg': [],
 'gender': ['Feminino'],
 'email': ['my_user@bol.com.br'],
 'phone_numbers': ['51999999999'],
 'photo': [],
 'id': 11111111,
 'duplicate_id': -1,
 'name': 'My User',
 'cnpj': [],
 'company_name': '[]',
 'city': [{'id': '0001', 'name': 'Porto Alegre'}],
 'state': [{'id': 100, 'name': 'Rio Grande do Sul', 'fs': 'RS'}],
 'type': 'Private Person',
 'tags': [],
 'pending_tickets_count': 0}

In [124]: data2 = {k:v for k,v in data.items() if k in required}

In [125]: data2
Out[125]:
{'birthday': ['1987-07-13T00:00:00.000Z'],
 'gender': ['Feminino'],
 'id': 11111111,
 'name': 'My User',
 'city': [{'id': '0001', 'name': 'Porto Alegre'}],
 'state': [{'id': 100, 'name': 'Rio Grande do Sul', 'fs': 'RS'}]}

In [126]: pd.DataFrame(data2).assign(
     ...:     city_name=lambda x: x['city'].str.get('name'),
     ...:     state_name=lambda x: x['state'].str.get('name'),
     ...:     state_fs=lambda x: x['state'].str.get('fs')
     ...:     ).drop(['state', 'city'], axis=1)
Out[126]:
                   birthday    gender        id     name     city_name         state_name state_fs
0  1987-07-13T00:00:00.000Z  Feminino  11111111  My User  Porto Alegre  Rio Grande do Sul       RS
```

reason why `data2` is required is that you can't have columns that differ in length. So in this case, `pd.DataFrame(data)` won't work as `rg` has 0 items but `birthday` has 1 item.

Also something to look at if you are directly dealing with json files is [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)